# Java to Javascript/HTML5 Canvas

Tags: java, javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering what the java to javascript/HTML5 translations were for these things:
1. Switching Activities/Layouts
2. Methods
3. Scanner Method (input via text box)

I am writing a game basically that is written in javascript and HTML5. HTML5 is being purely used to display the graphics via canvas. I am trying to create a menu for my game, but I was wondering how I would switch to another layout once I click the play button.

Comment: what does this have to do with java?

Comment: Java is the language I am most familiar with. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a million ways. However you feel most comfortable.

If you're looking for inspiration, here's one way that I do it. I have a function that repeatedly draws a menu until a button is pressed. When the button is pressed, the game loads and the old menu click event listeners are removed and new game click event listeners are added. I also end the old draw loop of the menu and start a new game draw loop. Here's some selected snippets to give you the idea of how its done:

```
Game.prototype.loadMenu = function() {
  var game = this;
  var can = this.canvas;

  // now we can use the mouse for the menu
  can.addEventListener('click', game.menuClickEvent, false);
  can.addEventListener('touchstart', game.menuClickEvent, false);

  // draw menu
  this.loop = setInterval(function() { game.drawMenu() }, 30);
};

Game.prototype.drawMenu = function() {
  // ... draw the menu
}

Game.prototype.loadLevel = function(levelstring) {
  // unload menu
  var can = this.canvas;
  var game = this;
  can.removeEventListener('click', game.menuClickEvent, false);
  can.removeEventListener('touchstart', game.menuClickEvent, false);

  if (this.loop) clearInterval(this.loop);

  // ... other level init stuff


  // now we can press keys for the game
  //can.addEventListener('click', game.gameClickEvent, false);
  can.addEventListener('touchstart', game.gameClickEvent, false);
  can.addEventListener('keydown', game.gameKeyDownEvent, false);

  this.loop = setInterval(function() { game.tick() }, 30);
}

// called from tick()
Game.prototype.draw = function(advanceFrame) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Simon when i try to call the function in the body onload or the head onload, it doesn't seem to work.